# Android - How to rotate Rect Object?

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I have a rectangle: `Rect r = new Rect();`. I want to rotate the `r` object to 45 degrees. I checked for solutions and I found that it can be done with matrices:

```
Matrix m = new Matrix();
// point is the point about which to rotate.
m.setRotate(degrees, point.x, point.y);
m.mapRect(r);
```

The problem is that whey I pass the `r` to `m.mapRect(r);` it complains that `r` should be from type `RectF`. I managed to do it like:

```
RectF r2 = new RectF(r);
Matrix m = new Matrix();
// point is the point about which to rotate.
m.setRotate(degrees, point.x, point.y);
m.mapRect(r2);
```

But the problem is that I need object from type `Rect` not `RectF` . Because I am passing the `r` object to external class which is taking a `Rect` object.

Is there another way to rotate the rectangle `r` form type `Rect` except this method and without rotationg the whole canvas(canvas contains some other elements)?

Thank you in advance!

Best regards, Dimitar Georgiev

Comment: You'd need to save the canvas, rotate and then redraw

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't create a new Rect with values taken from the rotated RectF and cast (or rounded) to integers?

Comment: @xBroak can you give me some more details like when and how i have to save and redraw?

Comment: @Torben I just tried and it is not working for some reason

Comment: @chikito1990 I don't believe that at all. Show code.

Comment: I have a question, when doing that, do the Rect points change?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rotating a rectangle this way will not get you anything usable for drawing. A Rect and a RectF do not store any information about rotation. When you use `Matrix.mapRect()`, the output RectF is just a new non-rotated rect whose edges touch the corner points of the rotated rectangle that you are wanting.

You need to rotate the whole canvas to draw the rectangle. Then immediately unrotate the canvas to continue drawing, so there is no issue with rotating the canvas that has other objects in it.

```
canvas.save();
canvas.rotate(45);
canvas.drawRect(r,paint);
canvas.restore();
```

Comment: **the output RectF is just a new non-rotated rect whose edges touch the corner points** is useful for me, but what i have to do in case of i want to rotate RectF , see my question at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33236473/how-to-rotate-view-by-coordinate-also-in-android

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this if you are applying rotation on your matrix then you should not use mapRect. you should figure out the 4 initial points representing each rectangle edge and use mapPoints instead.

```
float[] rectangleCorners = {
                            r2.left, r2.top, //left, top
                            r2.right, r2.top, //right, top
                            r2.right, r2.bottom, //right, bottom
                            r2.left, r2.bottom//left, bottom
                    };
Matrix m = new Matrix();
// point is the point about which to rotate.
m.setRotate(degrees, point.x, point.y);
m.mapPoints(r2);
```